# Error: The parameter 'event' of the method 'AlwaysWinPanGestureRecognizer... when importing color picker package in my project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

***Welcome***
I have a problem on importing [flutter_colorpicker package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colorpicker)
when i just import it in my project:
 `import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';`
I gets this error:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.5.0/lib/src/hsv_picker.dart:730:43: Error: The parameter 'event' of the method 'AlwaysWinPanGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer' has type 'PointerDownEvent', which does not match the corresponding type, 'PointerEvent', in the overridden method, 'DragGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer'.
 - 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
 - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
Change to a supertype of 'PointerEvent', or, for a covariant parameter, a subtype.
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
                                          ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/monodrag.dart:256:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('addAllowedPointer').
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerEvent event) {
       ^
```

this is the result of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1577], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

and this is project's dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.5.0
```

does anyone have a solution?
any thanks for every one

Comment: https://github.com/mchome/flutter_colorpicker/issues/49#issuecomment-861639045

Answer (score 11):

just change flutter_colorpicker version to 0.4.0

Comment: update change flutter_colorpicker version to ^0.6.1

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to add the covariant keyword to the method that
addAllowedPointer(covariant PointerEvent event) {

is giving an error, but this option would only solve the problem on your computer

Answer (score 0):

These might help :
Change dependencies in **pubspec.yaml** to :

```
dependencies: 
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  flutter_colorpicker: ^0.6.0
```

**Do run flutter clean and then add the dependency again it worked for me :)**